# Access NodePort through PortForward from the kubernetes master

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

**What I Have:** A Kubernetes Cluster on GCE with three Nodes. Lets suppose the master has the IP `<MasterIP>`. Additionally I have a Service within the cluster of Type NodePort which listens to the port `<PORT>`. I can access the service using `<NodeIP>:<PORT>`

**What I would like to do:** Access the service with `<MasterIP>:<PORT>` How can I forward the port from `<MasterIP>` to within the cluster? in other words: `<MasterIP>:<PORT> --> <NodeIP>:<PORT>`

The reason why I would like to do this is simply I don't want to rely on a specific `NodeIP` since the Pod can be rescheduled to another Node.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

A Kubernetes `Service` with `type: NodePort` opens the same port on every Node and sends the traffic to wherever the pod is currently scheduled using internal IP routing. You should be able to access the service at `<AnyNodeIP>:<PORT>`.

In Google's Kubernetes cluster, the master machines are not available for routing traffic. The way to reliably expose your services is to use a `Service` with `type: LoadBalancer` which will provide a single IP that resolves to your service regardless of which Nodes are up or what their IPs are.

Comment: Thanks. But what if the node crashes and gets another IP? This is why I would like to use not the NodeIP but the IP of the master.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. I've updated my answer to better address Google's Kubernetes cluster

Comment: The Problem is: I want to explicitly use NodePort so I guess my request is not possible.

Comment: Any reason you are trying to avoid LoadBalancer type? Your use case is specifically what they are designed for.

Comment: Yes. I want the service to be available only inside a Network but not externally from the internet.

Comment: You can use the internal load balancer